# While streaming from a webcam I'm getting error in detecting motion using AForge Library

Tags: c#, webcam, aforge

I have declared these:

```
// Motion Detection
AForge.Vision.Motion.MotionDetector motionDetector;
float detection;
```

and on Form's load event I have done this:

```
motionDetector = new AForge.Vision.Motion.MotionDetector(new AForge.Vision.Motion.TwoFramesDifferenceDetector(), new AForge.Vision.Motion.MotionBorderHighlighting());
detection = 0;
```

I have the following code:

```
void finalVideo_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
{
        Bitmap Streaming = new Bitmap((Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone(), webCam1.Size);
        Bitmap Frame = new Bitmap((Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone(), webCam1.Size);

        lock (Lock)
        {
            lock (Lock)
            {
                AddTimeStamp(Streaming);
            }

            lock (Lock) 
            {
                // Showing images in the pictureBox
                webCam1.Image = Streaming; 
            }
        }

        // Recording video
        if (writer != null)
        {
            if (RecordVideo.Checked)
            {
                try
                {
                    // create frame image
                    AddTimeStamp(Frame);

                    if(motionDetection.Checked)
                    {
                        // Detecting Motion
                        detection = motionDetector.ProcessFrame(Frame); [[[Getting Error Here]]]
                    }

                    // add frames to the video 
                    writer.AddFrame(Frame);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I am getting this error:

> The type 'AForge.Imaging.UnmanagedImage' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'AForge.Imaging, Version=2.2.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ba8ddea9676ca48b'.

I have already added the reference to `AForge.Imaging` but still I am getting this error. Please help

Comment: Have you verified the version? Is your reference in the correct project? Isn't there any exclamation mark or other warning icon of this sort next to the reference?

Comment: @BartoszKP yes i am using the same version that is AForge.NET Framework-2.2.5

Comment: @BartoszKP No there isn't any :s

Comment: There is no exclamation mark or any other icon next to the reference.

Comment: I have verified the version.
Reference is correct.
no exclamation mark or any other icon next to the reference.

Comment: I have three projects in the solution and i have added it to the correct project.

Comment: Only one of them uses AForge and the reference is there already.

Comment: OK, so you should edit your question: show how are the projects connected and where AForge types are being used. Even if project A uses project B, and only project B uses AForge, if any types "leak" into A, then the reference must also be added to project A.